# how to install an api to netbeans maven project Java

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, gmail, jakarta-mail

I was wondering how you actually install an API (mail API) to a maven project in Netbeans. I have searched up multiple tutorials and all of them say to add them into the library folder, but maven project only has dependencies. I am using: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ to install the API.

Setting the dependency, is that the same as installing the API?

[image]

Comment: Your tutorials are all defective. Adding a Maven dependency does add it to your project's libraries, which is what your screenshot shows. Dependencies aren't "installed", they're downloaded and added to the path of your project.

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Using `maven` to manage your project is just another way to structure and manage your Java Project. Like your IDE do, `maven` helps you manage your Java project `structure`, `external libraries`, `life cycle build`, `deployment` etc. 
At the other hand, most of the time, API you will use, are store in libraries (external jar) or an external Rest API. Thus 

> setting a dependency, is the same as installing an API 

through an external library dependency.